# Determining position of anchor boxes in original image using downsampled feature map

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection

From what I have read, I understand that methods used in faster-RCNN and SSD involve generating a set of anchor boxes. We first downsample the training image using a CNN and for every pixel in the downsampled feature map (which will form the center for our anchor boxes) we project it back onto the training image. We then draw the anchor boxes centered around that pixel using our pre-determined scales and ratios. What I dont understand is why dont we directly assume the centers of our anchor boxes on the training image with a suitable stride and use the CNN to only output the classification and regression values. What are we gaining by using the CNN to determine the centers of our anchor boxes which are ultimately going to be distributed evenly on the training image ?

To state more clearly -

Where will the centers of our anchor boxes be on the training image before our first prediction of the offset values and how do we decide those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion comes from this:

> What are we gaining by using the CNN to determine the centers of our anchor boxes which are ultimately going to be distributed evenly on the training image

The network usually doesn't predict centers but corrections to a prior belief. The initial anchor centers are distributed evenly across the image, and as such don't fit the objects in the scene tightly enough. Those anchors just constitute a prior in the probabilistic sense. What your network will exactly output is implementation dependent, but will likely just be updates, *i.e.* corrections to those initial priors. This means that the centers that are predicted by your network are some `delta_x, delta_y` that adjust the bounding boxes.

Regarding this part:

> why dont we directly assume the centers of our anchor boxes on the training image with a suitable stride and use the CNN to only output the classification and regression values

The regression values should still contain sufficient information to determine a bounding box in a unique way. Predicting width, height and center offsets (corrections) is a straightforward way to do it, but it's certainly not the only way. For example, you could modify the network to predict for each pixel, the distance vector to its nearest object center, or you could use parametric curves. However, crude, fixed anchor centers are not a good idea since they will also cause problems in classification, as you use them to pool features that are representative of the object.

Comment: Where will the centers of our anchor boxes be on the training image before our first prediction of the offset values and how do we decide those?

Comment: @physics123 Usually they are just defined as you suggested, uniformly with a given stride. Then at data associations, you associate some of the anchors to ground truth bounding boxes (with some criterion *e.g.* IOU), and compute the difference between the ground truth box and the anchor. Those increments are what your network will be trained to predict.

Comment: gateway2745 I have the exact same question as you and I still don't get it after reading  answer from @Ash. Can you explain me in your words what do we gain to determine anchor boxes positions from the feature maps? Or maybe Ash can clarify a bit?

Comment: Actually if you or @Ash has an answer, you can reply to my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053884/confused-about-retinanet-and-anchor-target-computation